# Ubuntu Distribution Upgrade to 12.04 freezes on configuring lswh

Tags: upgrade

For the last few hours, my upgrade window to 12.04 has been stalled at configuring lswh. The top of the terminal window says

> irqbalance start/running

There's a fairly long line of errors in the terminal like

> error cannot seek `/dev/sdc`,

most of them coming after the "Generating grub.cfg". A the very bottom of the terminal it says Found Ubuntu 8.04.2 on /dev/sdb3 and then "done" on the final line.

Reading other threads on freezes during upgrade1 gives me some hope I can open another terminal window and fix this and continue with the upgrade, but I haven't found what that command might be. I found some leads here where lshw hangs:

- bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lshw/+bug/218864

But the solution assumes I can just run a patch, which I can't don in the middle of an upgrade.

These two issues:

- http://eyemeansit.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/generating-grub-cfg-wont-finish/ and
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/194988

seem to suggestion killing or disabling the `os-prober`, but I'm not sure if I can do that mid-upgrade.

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL-C the upgrade, do whatever you want to do, then `dpkg --configure -a` to restart it.

Comment: No, the files should be okay - use sudo! Hmm strange... I would recommend backing up important files or moving them, and doing a fresh install - dist-upgrades cause a lot of problems when they go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help, whiskers75. I used sudo to make the change and it worked. Then I tried the dpkg --configure -a  to restart it and go "error: dpkg status database is locked by another process". It seems simply hitting ctrl+c in the dist-upgrade window didn't work. How do I kill the dist-upgrade process from another terminal?

Comment: `pkill apt-get` and `pkill dpkg`.

Comment: okay, the pkill worked and I was able to run 'dpkg --configure -a'. Now I run into a whole string of "dependency problems - leaving unconfigured" that conclude with "Processing was halted because there were too many errors."

Comment: `apt-get install -f` should fix dependency problems.

Comment: When I run `code'apt-get install -f'code` I get a very similar readout to dpkg, concluding with `Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Please post the entire readout. Use Pastebin if needed.

Comment: There isn't enough space in the box for the whole readout, but I think these are the key lines:

`debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing libpam-winbind (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up memtest86+ (4.20-1.1ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable`

I think the key process is /var/cache/debconf/config.dat,

Comment: /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is being used by the frontend process.

Comment: Here's the whole error list in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/tduPUXKT

Comment: Kill the frontend process - you seem to need that file.

Comment: Successfully killed the process. I ran the dpkg command again. Strangely it just kicks me back to the prompt after the following: http://pastebin.com/ystGt96A without listing any errors, at least not ones that appear terminal.

Comment: Well, run the dpkg --configure -a again, and you should be good to go! Looks like it has done upgrading you.

Comment: I should add that the key change I made to the system files that's not listed above was "The workaround I finally found (somewhere on Ubuntu forums, I think) was to append this line to the bottom of /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true" from http://eyemeansit.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/generating-grub-cfg-wont-finish/